# css not reflecting when executed

Tags: css

My css code reflects when i excecute it for all elements except box1 and container1 and i dont know how to fix that. I even tried to add another element replacing box1 and container one but I still ended up with the same results.

Css code:

```
\*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
 margin-right:40px;
 margin-right: 30px;
 margin-top:40px

}

\#box1{
border: 2px solid black;
width: 30%;
height: 80px
padding: 30px 40px 0px 10px;
margin-left: 90px
background: grey;
position: absolute;
right: 1000px;
float: right;

}

\#content1

{
border-color: black;

position: relative;
background-color: grey;
height: 40%;

}

\#box2{
border: 2px solid black;
width: 30%;
height: 29%;
padding: 50px 10px 30px 10px;
background: grey;
float: right;
position: absolute;
left: 480px;

}
\#content2 {
background-color: grey;
height: 40%;
border-color: black;
float: right;
position: absolute;

}
\#box3{
border: 2px solid black;
width: 33%;
height: 29%;
padding: 50px 10px 0px 10px;
background: grey;
 float: right;
position: absolute;
margin-left: 900px

}
\#content3 {
background-color: grey;
height: 40%;
margin-left: 15px
border-color: black;
position: absolute;
float: right;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Assignment solutionn for module 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


<h1 style="text-align: center;">Our menue..</h1>

<div id="box3">
    <div id= "content3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do       eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis     nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure     dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.     Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim      id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>

<div id= "box2">
    <div id="content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do     eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis      nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure     dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.     Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim      id est laborum.
    </div>
</div>

<div id="box1">
    <div id="content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum...
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your very first step would be to check both the HTML and the CSS against a syntax validator.  When you do that, are there any problems found?  (Note: Using a proper IDE allows for built-in syntax checking as you write the code.)

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to use semicolon (;) in end of some of your CSS rules

`height: 80px`

```
       #box1{
           border: 2px solid black;
           width: 30% ;
           height: 80px ;
           padding: 30px 40px 0px 10px;
           margin-left: 90px;
           background: grey;
           position: absolute;
           right: 1000px;
           float: right;
        }
```

Comment: Yes, could be the culprit. @Ariana Samimi Such a thing is easily caught by building your code in an IDE; you would get a noticeable alert about the problem..